# Как найти площадь пересекающихся частей 2-х прямоугольников в ABAP?

Tags: java, c#, abap

Всем добрый день! Есть такая задача, решение которой нужно написать на языке ABAP:

На плоскости заданы два прямоугольника. Каждый прямоугольник задается координатами двух противоположных вершин. Найти площадь пересечения этих прямоугольников. Замечание. Стороны прямоугольников параллельны осям координат.

Входные данные
В первой строке записаны четыре числа — координаты двух противоположных вершин первого прямоугольника. Во второй строке записаны четыре числа — координаты двух противоположных вершин второго прямоугольника. Прямоугольники могут вырождаться в отрезки и даже точки. Все координаты — целые числа от 0 до 40 000.

Подскажите в каком направлении думать и как можно решить эту задачу?  Опыта в ABAPе нет вообще.

Как вы считаете, насколько высокий уровень сложности у этой задачи?

И почему не получилось создать метку ABAP и никто ее на этом форуме до сих пор не создал? Неужели настолько редкий язык, что он никому не интересен?

Comment: 1. Понять как найти пересечение прямоугольников (можно посмотреть у другие языки, например java, там есть java.awt.Rectangle, у которого такой функционал есть). 2. перенести код в ABAP

Comment: метку ABAP создал, действительно странно, что ее не было до сих пор

Comment: Язык редкий и узкопрофильный. Да и в программисты на этом языке самоучки не попадают, только после обучения. Соответственно, шанс встретить человека, у которого _опыта в ABAPе нет вообще_, но _есть задача_, ничтожно мал.

Comment: 4-мя этажами ниже меня сидит пара сотен абаперов :)

Comment: на англоязычном Stackoverflow очень мало (по отношению ко всему прочему) вопросов на abap да и на SAP в целом а уж на рускоязычном и подавно, вот тега и не было. Абаперы и консы в основном на форумах на саповском сайте (https://www.sap.com/community.html) или на http://sapboard.ru/ или на http://sapboard.ru/forum/ сидят

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм такой:

- `r1`, `r2` = rectangle 1 или 2
- `x`, `y` = соответствующая координата
- `l`, `r`, `t`, `b` = left, right, top, bottom (ось y напралена вниз)
- `res` = площадь пересечения (если не пересекаются, то 0)

```
r1x1 r1y1 r1x2 r1y2
r2x1 r2y1 r2x2 r2y2

r1l = min(r1x1, r1x2)
r1r = max(r1x1, r1x2)
r1t = min(r1y1, r1y2)
r1b = max(r1y1, r1y2)

r2l, r2r, r2t, r2b = ...

l = max(r1l, r2l)
r = min(r1r, r2r)
t = max(r1t, r2t)
b = min(r1b, r2b)

res = max(r - l, 0) * max(b - t, 0)
```

Comment: а вы код выше на каком языке написали?

Comment: просто псевдокод. в первых двух строках переменные, в которые надо поместить входные данные, а дальше вычисления. вместо многоточия надо написать код, аналогичный предыдущему блоку.

Answer (score 0):

В Java это делается так:

```
Rectangle rect1, rect2;
Rectangle intersection=rect1.intersection(rect2); //возвращает пересечение rect1 и rect2
double area=intersection.width*intersection.height;
```

В ABAP я думаю примерно так же и решается.

Comment: А если не пересекаются не упадёт?

Comment: Да хз - может и упадет :)

Answer (score 0):

Был 2-х летний опыт программирования на ABAP/4 
 
И я не помню что бы в ABAP были какие-то готовые библиотеки/функции даже для самых простых вещей типа min/max/sort/collections и т.д.
 
Поэтому сложность задачи будет равно сложности написать это все псевдокодом
Уверен, что в процедурном стиле будет проще написать чем в OOP для ABAP
Также редактор в SAP/R3(зависит от версии конечно) далек от любой привычной IDE